# Can anyone tell me how to control the DC motors using ROS and Arduino

Tags: ros, arduino, rosserial

[image: Rosanswers logo]

i am fairly new to ROS. I'm trying to control 2 DC motors through ROS and Arduino. I've been using rosserial package and also i've tried ros_arduino_bridge.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/254460/can-anyone-tell-me-how-to-control-the-dc-motors-using-ros-and-arduino/) by [antonchi](https://answers.ros.org/users/29336/antonchi/) on ROS Answers with karma: 1 on 2017-02-12

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [NEngelhard](https://answers.ros.org/users/18581/nengelhard/) on 2017-02-12**:
The title is fort a short 'title', could you please try to edit your question into a title (one line) and a question (as long as needed?)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

On the smaller Arduinos with only 2kb RAM I've had trouble using rosserial because of the amount of RAM consumed, so I've abandoned that for ros_arduino_bridge. If you are using a motor driver not already supported by ros_arduino_bridge, you'll have to modify the code in a couple of places.

First, in ROSArduinoBridge.ino, look at this code (lines 48-64):

```
//#define USE_BASE      // Enable the base controller code
#undef USE_BASE     // Disable the base controller code

/* Define the motor controller and encoder library you are using */
#ifdef USE_BASE
   /* The Pololu VNH5019 dual motor driver shield */
   #define POLOLU_VNH5019

   /* The Pololu MC33926 dual motor driver shield */
   //#define POLOLU_MC33926

   /* The RoboGaia encoder shield */
   #define ROBOGAIA
   
   /* Encoders directly attached to Arduino board */
   //#define ARDUINO_ENC_COUNTER
#endif
```

You need to uncomment the definition of USE_BASE, comment out ROBOGAIA, and then add your own define for your motor controller, say `#define RKI1340_MOTOR_CONTROLLER`.

Then, in motor_driver.ino, you'll need to add code to support that motor driver. The bottom of that file looks like this:

```
#else
  #error A motor driver must be selected!
#endif
```

You'll need to add an `#elif` before the `#else` for `RKI1340_MOTOR_CONTROLLER`, and add a definition of `void setMotorSpeeds(int leftSpeed, int rightSpeed)`.

There are other changes required to support encoders different from the ones already coded. You might compare with the changes Marco Walther made to support the Pololu A-Star board with onboard motor driver. (I've contributed to his mods.)

https://github.com/mw46d/ros_arduino_bridge/tree/indigo-devel/ros_arduino_firmware/src/libraries/ROSArduinoBridge

---

Originally posted by [Mark Rose](https://answers.ros.org/users/27558/mark-rose/) with karma: 1563 on 2017-02-12

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1